# How to put my input and buttons wrapped nicely in a div tag

Tags: html, css

I need your help,

I can't seem to figure out as to why my elements appear the way that they do. I'd like to have them centered in a div with a background color but for some reason, my div goes into the back and my elements seem like they are outside the div tag

I've attached a pic and am using ie 10.

Here is the markup:

```
<!--        BUTTONS         -->
<div style="width: auto; margin-top: 5px; background-color: rgb(223,223,223); border: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128); padding: 5px;">


        <div style="float: left;"><input type="button" value="<<"></div>
        <div style="float: left;"><input type="button" value="<"></div>
        <div style="float: left;"><input type="text"></div>
        <div style="float: left;">of</div>
        <div style="float: left;"><input type="text"></div>
        <div style="float: left;"><input type="button" value=">"></div>
        <div style="float: left;"><input type="button" value=">>"></div>



</div>
```

[image]

Comment: You probably haven't cleared the floats. Try adding `overflow:hidden` to the wrapping div

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to clear the float like bellow:

```
<!--        BUTTONS         -->
<div style="width: auto; margin-top: 5px; background-color: rgb(223,223,223); border: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128); padding: 5px;">


        <div style="float: left;"><input type="button" value="<<"></div>
        <div style="float: left;"><input type="button" value="<"></div>
        <div style="float: left;"><input type="text"></div>
        <div style="float: left;">of</div>
        <div style="float: left;"><input type="text"></div>
        <div style="float: left;"><input type="button" value=">"></div>
        <div style="float: left;"><input type="button" value=">>"></div>


        <!-- Add this here to clear the floats -->
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

## [See jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Ta57/)

Answer (score 0):

Add `<div style="clear:both">` after your last input

Answer (score 0):

since you are using float in your style that why everything goes out of the flow from parent div. you can fix this by placing the `overflow:hidden` property.

on your parent div you have to only add `overflow:hidden` and it will work like charm.

```
<div style="width: auto; margin-top: 5px; background-color: rgb(223,223,223); border: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128); padding: 5px;overflow:hidden;">
    <div style="float: left;"><input type="button" value="<<"></div>
        <div style="float: left;"><input type="button" value="<"></div>
        <div style="float: left;"><input type="text"></div>
        <div style="float: left;">of</div>
        <div style="float: left;"><input type="text"></div>
        <div style="float: left;"><input type="button" value=">"></div>
        <div style="float: left;"><input type="button" value=">>"></div>
```

Here is the Demo as well. http://jsbin.com/zixepizi/1/